# Create a certificate signing request

Tags: certificate-authority, public-key-infrastructure

can someone please tell me a few tools that can be used to create a CSR ?

Comment: It would help to indicate the environment you're in: OS, language, or whatever matters.

Comment: Is this strictly a security question, or a how-to on tool-of-choice?

Comment: Asking for product recommendations are not a good fit for SE sites. Please see the [FAQ], also read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

OpenSSL can do CSR's: [OpenSSL: Documents, req(1)](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html#)

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, it is very much platform/application specific. Usually a google search with platform+csr will give you some useful results.

E.g. [this](http://www.geocerts.com/csr/iis_6) guide for IIS6.